# How does magic quotes access the array element containing "-" in name?

Tags: php, magic-quotes

I was going through a manual and found a statement saying "if array element used with '-' as the word separator, the array's element can be accessed by magic quotes".. but didn't provided with any explanations on it. could some one explain the reason behind this?

Comment: What manual? A link would be helpful.

Comment: its a company's coding standard manual

Comment: BTW Magic quotes are bad m'kay

Comment: I am aware of it but I want to know how does this work

Comment: PHP doesn't support selective application of magic quotes.  Either your coding standards manual is wrong, or it's using terminology incorrectly (it means something other than what it says).  That or you're using a customized PHP build internally, or are building on top of a custom framework that does it.

Comment: If it is the company manual, then you should have access to the author. Ask them.

Comment: Why The hell it is being voted to  close.. I am not asking anything irrelevant here....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's seemingly this one (since OP won't tell us):
http://www.dagbladet.no/development/phpcodingstandard/#arrayelement

Here "magic quotes" is simply the wrong designation. They mean double quoted string interpolation, specifically:

```
print "$myarr[foo_bar] world";
```

versus

```
print "$myarr[foo-bar] world";   // invalid
```

And indeed only the first one is correct syntax. Else use curly braces and key quotes:

```
print "{$myarr['foo-bar']} world";
```

Comment: Hey Yes.. This is the manual They Have used... But here also They have menioned about the "magic quotes" in justification

Comment: Is the same misdesignation. They are talking about double quoted strings once more. The warnings are notices for undeclared constants. Which is what happens for unquoted array keys in PHP code, not in double quote context.